# How to change div height if browser height is less than a given number of pixels?

Tags: javascript, html, css, height, window-resize

I have a div that I want to be one of two sizes.

- If browser window height is smaller than a given height, then it uses the smaller height for the div
- However, if browser window height is larger than given height, then it uses larger height for the div

I tried the following code but it's not working. I need help to get it working.

Here is the jsbin: http://jsbin.com/oFIRawa/1

And here is the code I have so far:

**page.html**

```
<div id="theDiv">&nbsp;</div>
```

**style.css**

```
#theDiv {
    background: #000;
    border: 2px solid #222;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
}
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // call the method one time
    updateWindowSize();
    // subscribe the method to future resize events
    $(window).resize(updateWindowSize);

    // variables
     var updateWindowSize = (function(){
        var minAllowedWindowHeight = 500;
        var largerDivHeight = 400;
        var smallerDivHeight = 300;

        // actual updateWindowSize function
        return function(){
            var winHeight = $(window).height();
            var newHeight = winHeight < minAllowedWindowHeight ? smallerDivHeight : largerDivHeight;
            $('#theDiv').height(newHeight);
        };
     })();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in CSS my good sir. It's called responsive design!

```
@media (max-height:500px) {
    Enter special css conditions for 500px height.
}

@media (max-height:200px) {
    Enter special css conditions for 200px height.
}
```

This is more commonly used for max-width because it can tell us when someone is using a mobile device (something like 360px max-width), then we can modify our page to look nice on mobile. No fancy javascript needed!

Comment: I don't understand how to use this. Where do I define the minimum WINDOW height and where do I define specific ID?

Comment: I don't understand why you have two separate rules here? You only need one?

Comment: You put this code in your .css file. It's not javascript, it's css. or you can put it in style tags on your index page. I just put two rules as an example, that you can do it for multiple heights. Here's a quick example for you! [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/z5W9j/), resize the bottom right window to see the box change color based on height. All you need to do is change the height at which this happens at (200px) and change the size of the div instead of the color.

Comment: OH! Thanks for the example! EXACTLY what I needed! Very easy fix, and no javascript needed! Accepted as best answer!

Comment: Wonderful solution, I just implemented this on my page and it works perfectly! Was easily able to define multiple styles based on window height!

Answer (score 2):

```
var threshhold;
var smallerHeight = 50;
var largerHeight = 100;

if ($(window).height() < threshold)
    $('#theDiv').height(smallerHeight);
else
    $('#theDiv').height(largerHeight);
```

**FIDDLE**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jmhwn/)

Comment: that's exactly the same thing I have except I used the variable name of `minAllowedWindowHeight` instead of `threshhold` variable name. Also you forgot to define a number for `threshhold`. i.e. `threshhold = 500;` Anyway, being as this is exact same thing as is in my question, it of course doesn't work.

Comment: @user2845197 Did you look at the error? You have an error, this is why it's not working.

Comment: This works in your jsfiddle! Thank you; only thing is I had to accept other as best answer because they did it even simpler without even any javascript. But your solution DOES work, too bad I can't choose two best answers! At the very least I voted you up :)

Comment: I agree, the other answer is better. I only posted mine as completeness!